# SwiftUI - List of textfields, observe value changes from an array

Tags: swiftui

I have a list of textfields, and I want to update the server once the value changes.
I want to ideally use Combine so I can debounce and stagger the updates a bit.
However, I'm unsure of the best practice to track changes to individual objects.
Observing an array doesn't work because it's observing the array (i.e adds, removes)

```
struct SomeItem {
    let id: Int
    var text: String
}
```

````
final class SomeViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items = [
        SomeItem(id: 0, text: "Zero"),
        SomeItem(id: 1, text: "One")
    ]

    @State var cancellables = [AnyCancellable]()

    init() {
        observe()
    }

    /// Observe changes of items so I can post updates to the server when one changes.
    ///
    /// Potentially something like the following, but arrays dont work like this:
    ///```
    /// items
    ///   .publisher
    ///   .debounce(for: 0.2, scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
    ///   .sink { change in
    ///     updateItem(with: change.id)
    ///   }
    ///   .store(in: &cancellables)
    /// ```
    func observe() {
        // ..
    }
    
    /// Updates an item on server.
    func updateItem(with id: Int) {
        // ..
    }
}
````

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = SomeViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        List($viewModel.items, id: \.id) { $item in
            TextField("text", text: $item.text)
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: In SwiftUI, You don’t “observe” changes in the UI: you simply set an action on a Button or on the change of the TextField. Call updateItem() from the view.

Answer (score 0):

The `items` in this design is a monolithic value from *publishing* perspective, meaning you cannot separate which part of it changed from inside.

A possible approach is to use proxy binding with side-effect, so we update item value directly and have id to pass into some function that perform some after-process, like scheduling into some queue for update (which can be bulk by itself, by the way)

```
List($viewModel.items, id: \.id) { $item in
    let binding = Binding(
        get: { item.text },
        set: {
            item.text = $0
            // push item in some queue for delayed background update to server
            // enqueueUpdateItem(with: item.id)  // or even all `item`
        }
    )
    TextField("text", text: binding)
}
```